Read the site collection URLs in CSV file and replace/add the Email ID.in the "Allow access requests" settings
I want to read CSV file which consist of Site collection URLs and replace the "Allow access requests" email ID.
In CSV file, I have data like below.
SiteURL - ColumnName
https://example.com/sites/test1
https://example.com/sites/test2
I have developed below script,
#Config Variables
$CSVPath = "C:\Temp\ListofURLs.csv"
#Get Data from CSV
$CSVData = Import-CSV -Path $CSVPath
#Connect to PnP Online
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $Row.SiteURL -Interactive
#Update Access Request Email
Set-PnPRequestAccessEmails -Emails @("example@example.com")
But, It is replacing/adding first SharePoint site URL in the CSV file but i have lot of URLs in the CSV file and how to do loop for all the URLs of site collections to replace with the provided email.

This is more a programming question about how to loop in a PowerShell array than a SharePoint related question. StackOverflow could be a better place to ask.

Please try this:
#Config Variables 
$CSVPath = "C:\Temp\ListofURLs.csv"

#Get Data from CSV 
$CSVData = Import-CSV -Path $CSVPath
$Counter =1

#Connect to PnP Online 
ForEach($Row in $CSVPath){
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $Row.SiteURL -Interactive 
#Update Access Request Email 
Set-PnPRequestAccessEmails -Emails @("example@example.com")
Write-Host "The request access email of $Row.SiteURL has updated!"
$Counter++
}

